# Generating a GUID/UUID in KRL

Tags: krl

Is there a built-in function in KRL for generating a GUID of UUID (or something similar)?

Comment: there is not yet a dedicated guid or uuid function, but there may be something that fits your needs. Do you have a particular format that you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a module that wraps a webservice that might hold you over: [UUID Module](http://apps.kynetx.com/modules/a8x164)

Use like so:

```
ruleset a8x165 {
    meta {
        name "UUID Module Example"
        description <<
            Example use of the UUID Module
        >>
        author "Sam Curren"
        logging off
        use module a8x164 alias uuid
    }

    dispatch {}

    global {}

    rule first_rule {
        select when pageview ".*" setting ()
        pre {
            testuuid = uuid:new_uuid();
        }
        notify("Hello World", "This is a UUID: #{testuuid}");
    }
}
```